# Is it possible to use the meiomask jQuery plugin to format a string according to some mask?

Tags: jquery

I am using [meiomask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) to mask input. There is a label where I display the result of a certain computation. I would like this result to be formatted as decimal-us, but this is not an input field. In fact, this is not even a label - it is just text inside a table cell.

I wonder if I can use meiomask to format a string according to a mask in a sort of off-line mode, no input field attached.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**

I am aware that I can use read-only input fields. The question, though, is interesting in itself.

Comment: Would you consider grabbing the val of a hidden input? I think the alternative is modding the plugin...

Comment: Nope, I do not want to create any DOM elements just for that.

Answer (score 0):

meiomask has a [string](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/blob/master/jquery.meio.mask.js#L282) function which you can use to mask any string with any mask.